# stk._Get_container();

Tags: c++11

Возникла такая проблема
не работает метод стека **_Get_container();**
просто компилятор не знает такой метод
подскажите решение этой проблемы
CODE::BLOCKS со стандартом c++11

Comment: а какой тип у stk - что это?

Comment: Что такое stk??

Comment: Я так понял это стек

Comment: да, это  стек stl )

Answer (score 0):

`_Get_container()` - это специфическая функция от студийного компилятора. А когда Вы переключились на CODE::BLOCK, то автоматически получили gcc, который это не поддерживает.

Что же делать? Нужно писать код так, что бы не нужно было использовать "нижележащий контейнер". Возможно, нужно просто использовать vector или deque.

Если же очень сильно хочется, то можно использовать различные хаки. Например, как [описано здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/90683/) - но это исключительно в развлекательных целях.

Comment: Спасибо вам за объяснение)
а то не мог понять в чем дело)